# Webcomic where a blond gynoid becomes a pop superstar with a cover of "Don't Hate Me 'Cause I'm Beautiful"

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, webcomics

Tom Smith's "[And They Say I've Got Talent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4w37khbmh6s)" came up in my playlist and I was suddenly struck with misty memories of a webcomic I read at least a decade ago where, for some scheme or another, someone (an alien?) decides to engineer a pop star, programming a blonde gynoid to sing "Don't Hate Me 'Cause I'm Beautiful", and it's a runaway success, except that something goes wrong as these schemes tend to, except I don't remember what. I want to say that the gynoid developed a sense of self, hated her vapid act, and decided to become independent of her creator.

My mental image of the singer robot is that she looked like [Conquest](https://walkypedia.fandom.com/wiki/Conquest) from the Walkyverse. I'll try to provide more details as I think of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out with a bit more searching via Google.

The gynoid is [Jalea Bates](http://www.thefullwiki.org/Melonpool#Crew_of_the_Steel_Duck) from [*Melonpool*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/OldSchoolMelonpool) (warning, TV Tropes link).

> Jalea Bates was originally a protocol droid named J-LB8 (rumored to be the silver droid at the beginning of Star Wars), the then male droid was disassembled in the late 80s after a messy paternity suit threatened to ruin him.
>
> In 2001, Ralph Zinobop accidentally sold half of J-LB8's parts at a garage sale. He assembled the remaining parts into a Pop-Singing android named Jalea Bates. Jalea has had quite the singing career, including such hits as "Don't Hate Me Because I'm Beautiful" and "Overdue," songs which can be downloaded from the audio/visual section of the Melonpool page.
>
> In 2002, Jalea's body was destroyed and her mind uploaded into the ship's computer during the "Zinoforming" process to make an asteroid Mayberry had got the ship stranded upon hospitable for the crew. Ralph made another body for her out of a vacuum cleaner and uploaded her mind into it. Several months later it was revealed that the Zinoforming process regenerated her body into a real human being, The human was a primitive hunter, and a mind swap using one of Ralph's inventions put Jalea into the human body and the hunter into the vacuum.
>
> Since then, Jalea has been finding out what it means to really be human and currently acts as navigator aboard The "Steel Duck." She has recently attempted to revive her singing career but has found her voice lacking following her reconstruction as a real human being. Whether this was due to nerves, lack of practice, or the complete loss of her talent is unknown.

[image: Strip with Jalea singing during the crossover with the Walkyverse]

What complicated things a bit was that Jalea's singing career was from the original webcomic continuity, which was purged from the web when Steve Troop rebooted the strip (although he still sells paper books of those strips as *Old School Melonpool*).

Comment: I wonder whether the joke is that "jalarse" in Spanish, literally meaning to pull, is a colloquial way of saying "to masturbate." So this could just be a bilingual version of those terrible "Master Bates" puns.

Comment: @Adamant The joke is that the original robot name, "J-LB8" can be read as "jail bait"; attractive but underage female, aka, a ticket to jail if you try to do anything with her. It was a general joke about teen pop stars, since that's what Jalea Bates parodies.